# Youtube API channel search skipping videos in list

Tags: youtube-api

I've got an app that's making an API call to YouTube that grabs the most recent videos by a certain channel. Suddenly, the list it is producing is incomplete.

I've manually searched the specific video it does grab, and one that it skips to compare the JSON result to see if there was something that made the videos differ, but as far as I can tell, aside from the obvious logical differences (title, id, etc;) there are none.

The original channel search call looks like this:
`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UCi8e0iOVk1fEOogdfu4YgfA&maxResults=10&order=date&type=video&key={API_KEY}`

The response is a list that consistently skips around 4 videos for seemingly no reason.

Here is an example of a video it skips when I make a call to the specific ID:

```
    "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
    "etag": "\"p4VTdlkQv3HQeTEaXgvLePAydmU/DoiqTSh7UcwtVvH87b5HIMkDSAA\"",
    "pageInfo": {
        "totalResults": 1,
        "resultsPerPage": 1
    },
    "items": [
        {
            "kind": "youtube#video",
            "etag": "\"p4VTdlkQv3HQeTEaXgvLePAydmU/psJBlwJjAqrqgzcYJJIcvpK4mrI\"",
            "id": "txDYwh46tew",
            "snippet": {
                "publishedAt": "2019-09-17T18:00:40.000Z",
                "channelId": "UCi8e0iOVk1fEOogdfu4YgfA",
                "title": "The Secret Garden International Trailer #1 (2020) | Movieclips Trailers",
                "description": [removed for stackoverflow formatting],
                "thumbnails": {
                    "default": {
                        "url": [removed for stackoverflow formatting],
                        "width": 120,
                        "height": 90
                    },
                    "medium": {
                        "url": [removed for stackoverflow formatting],
                        "width": 320,
                        "height": 180
                    },
                    "high": {
                        "url": [removed for stackoverflow formatting],
                        "width": 480,
                        "height": 360
                    },
                    "standard": {
                        "url": [removed for stackoverflow formatting],
                        "width": 640,
                        "height": 480
                    },
                    "maxres": {
                        "url": [removed for stackoverflow formatting],
                        "width": 1280,
                        "height": 720
                    }
                },
                "channelTitle": "Movieclips Trailers",
                "tags": [
                    "The Secret Garden",
                    "The Secret Garden Trailer",
                    "The Secret Garden Movie Trailer",
                    "The Secret Garden Trailer 2019",
                    "The Secret Garden Official Trailer",
                    "Trailer",
                    "Trailers",
                    "Movie Trailers",
                    "2019 Trailers",
                    "The Secret Garden Trailer 1",
                    "Movieclips Trailers",
                    "Movieclips",
                    "Fandango",
                    "Entertainment",
                    "Movies",
                    "Drama",
                    "Family",
                    "Fantasy",
                    "Marc Munden",
                    "Colin Firth",
                    "Maeve Dermody",
                    "Julie Walters"
                ],
                "categoryId": "1",
                "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
                "localized": {
                    "title": "The Secret Garden International Trailer #1 (2020) | Movieclips Trailers",
                    "description": [removed for stackoverflow formatting]
                },
                "defaultAudioLanguage": "en"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And here is a similar example in a video that it successfully returns in the original broader search:

```
{
    "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
    "etag": "\"p4VTdlkQv3HQeTEaXgvLePAydmU/kvDQkVJCJaguSZLpfF9hJWR7sVw\"",
    "pageInfo": {
        "totalResults": 1,
        "resultsPerPage": 1
    },
    "items": [
        {
            "kind": "youtube#video",
            "etag": "\"p4VTdlkQv3HQeTEaXgvLePAydmU/WYxiNVjYVTjfwUuXqUpGeoV4KDA\"",
            "id": "C8HrLHSBVJo",
            "snippet": {
                "publishedAt": "2019-09-16T22:22:16.000Z",
                "channelId": "UCi8e0iOVk1fEOogdfu4YgfA",
                "title": "Know Before You Go: Rambo: Last Blood | Movieclips Trailers",
                "description": [removed for stackoverflow formatting],
                "thumbnails": {
                    "default": {
                        "url": [removed for stackoverflow formatting],
                        "width": 120,
                        "height": 90
                    },
                    "medium": {
                        "url": [removed for stackoverflow formatting],
                        "width": 320,
                        "height": 180
                    },
                    "high": {
                        "url": [removed for stackoverflow formatting],
                        "width": 480,
                        "height": 360
                    },
                    "standard": {
                        "url": [removed for stackoverflow formatting],
                        "width": 640,
                        "height": 480
                    },
                    "maxres": {
                        "url": [removed for stackoverflow formatting],
                        "width": 1280,
                        "height": 720
                    }
                },
                "channelTitle": "Movieclips Trailers",
                "tags": [
                    "rambo last blood know before you go",
                    "know before you go",
                    "fandango",
                    "movieclips",
                    "trailers",
                    "rambo",
                    "last blood",
                    "rambo last blood",
                    "Sylvester Stallone",
                    "Paz Vega",
                    "Yvette Monreal",
                    "Adrian Grunberg",
                    "action",
                    "adventure",
                    "thriller",
                    "first blood",
                    "all rambo movies",
                    "rambo movies",
                    "rambo movies explained",
                    "rambo franchise explained",
                    "slyvester stallone",
                    "rambo explained",
                    "new rambo movie",
                    "new rambo trailer",
                    "sylvester stallone rambo"
                ],
                "categoryId": "1",
                "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
                "defaultLanguage": "en",
                "localized": {
                    "title": "Know Before You Go: Rambo: Last Blood | Movieclips Trailers",
                    "description": [removed for stackoverflow formatting]
                },
                "defaultAudioLanguage": "en"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The Channel IDs both match, and the publish date shows that the skipped video is more recently published than the video it successfully finds. Considering the original call is set to order the by date, there should be no reason the skipped video would be left out of the results. Of the found videos, they are correctly ordered in chronological order, so it doesn't seem to be the order parameter either.

I would expect the API search result to respond with an unfiltered list of the 10 newest videos published on the channels. Up until a couple days ago, it was performing that with no issue. With no changes to the call, it has suddenly started missing videos in a consistent behaviour. I'm at a loss for why that behaviour would suddenly change.